# How to add A-Z bar on the right side of a table view in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I want to have an A-Z bar on the right side of a table view in Swift 3. I'm not sure what exactly this is called and am having a tough time finding a tutorial for it. I have a list that I already sorted, but I'd like to be able to have the A-Z scroll on the side the user could press to snap to a certain section. Can anyone explain how to do this with the updated Swift 3 syntax/methods?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UITableView` and `UITableViewDataSource`. It's the section index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only if your table has sections. It doesn't have to display any section headers, but it must use sections. You can then implement [`sectionIndexTitles`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614857-sectionindextitles).